# Ext Dependency Builder in POPUP window

Tags: javascript, extjs, popup

I have a big problem that makes me go crazy ...
I want to add into a popup window a "Ext Dependency Builder" component ... using the components here:
"http://extjs.com/deploy/ext/docs/index.html"

> dialog = new Ext.LayoutDialog("name1", {layout parameters})

where "name1" is the name of a div on my main jsp page.

I need to add a `Ext.BorderLayout("name2", {layout parameters})`

So I guess I should use another div with id="name2" ... does div name2 be included in name1 or how should I use them???

any help / exemples would be greatly appreciated :)

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

These components are part of Ext 1.1. The current standard is Ext 2.2, with 3.0 being released probably in June. The API changed significantly between 1.x and 2.x (with the upgrade to 3 being very backwards compatible to 2.x). You can view a Samples and Demos page for 2.x at the following:

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html

And the API documentation:

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/

Also, if you go to the downloads page you will find the Ext 3.0 RC download, along with the 2.2 downloads (1.1 is no longer available for download, as far as I know).

To get a BorderLayout in 2.x/3.x, you would have something like the following:

```
var myModalWindow = new Ext.Window({
    applyTo:'name1',
    layout: 'border',
    items:[{
        region:'north',
        html:'<h1>This is a header of some kind</h1>'
    },{
        region:'west',
        xtype:'tree',
        // The rest of my TreePanel config
    },{
        region:'center',
        xtype:'tabpanel',
        activeTab:0,
        items:[{
            xtype:'grid',
            // the rest of my GridPanel config
        },{
            xtype:'form',
            // the rest of my FormPanel config
        }]
    }]
});
myModalWindow.show();
```

Comment: BTW, In the future, please tag your Ext questions with ExtJS. They'll get seen by more people.